# も particle after an adverb

Tags: particles, adverbs, particle-も

I know that も particle can be used in place of は、が、を. And it means "in addition", "also".

What function does it have in this adverb "不運にも"?
Should we treat it as a separate word here?

Comment: Do you have more context for this?  It will make it easier to answer.

Comment: Yes, please give the full sentence.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[『中上級を教える人のための日本語文法ハンドブック』](http://www.amazon.co.jp/gp/product/4883192016) explains the expression `不運にも` on p. 382 as *a sentence adverb* (文副詞).

Some adjectives like `不運な`, `幸運な`, `意外な`, `皮肉な`, `勇敢な`, `卑怯な`, etc. can take `も` after their conjuntive form to add some *evaluation, criticism, or commentary* of speaker to the whole sentence.

For example, the sentense

> 意外にも、彼は集会に現れた。 (Surprisingly, he showed up to the assembly.)

expresses *indirectly* that the speaker did not expect that he would show up. This *unexpectedness* is not the main topic of this sentence, but a kind of commentary from the speaker's point of view.

Here is another example:

> その警察官は勇敢にもギャングから人質を救出した。 (The policeman bravely rescued the hostages from the gang.)

Comment: [Here is a link to the page](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=0eprLex8sr0C&pg=PA382&lpg=PA382&dq=%E6%96%87%E5%89%AF%E8%A9%9E+%E4%B8%8D%E9%81%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82&source=bl&ots=4JIjy3ADmC&sig=o8VQtWTzA1jJoa9vfC6nNOzDLYs&hl=ja&sa=X&ei=eEeUUIaQMaSImQXC4IDYCg&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%E6%96%87%E5%89%AF%E8%A9%9E%20%E4%B8%8D%E9%81%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82&f=false) on google books. Also, +1 from me.

Answer (score 2):

`不運にも` could be considered a set phrase. However, technically the も there puts more emphasis on the phrase (強調を加える).
(**EDIT**: After reading [the referenced book mentioned by Tsutomu](http://books.google.co.jp/books?id=0eprLex8sr0C&pg=PA382&lpg=PA382&dq=%E6%96%87%E5%89%AF%E8%A9%9E+%E4%B8%8D%E9%81%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82&source=bl&ots=4JIjy3ADmC&sig=o8VQtWTzA1jJoa9vfC6nNOzDLYs&hl=ja&sa=X&ei=eEeUUIaQMaSImQXC4IDYCg&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%E6%96%87%E5%89%AF%E8%A9%9E%20%E4%B8%8D%E9%81%8B%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82&f=false) it can be concluded that this usage is fixed for certain words. I suggest everybody to read the linked page from google books.)

Perhaps other examples would make it more clear:

> 日本の[財政赤字]{ざいせいあかじ}が９００兆円にも上る

The `も` in the above sentence emphasizes just how bad the debt is getting.

Another example of `にも` is when you want to emphasize どうしてもできない:

> 歩くにも歩けないほど人が多い (There are so many people I can't even walk)

This will always be in the form ～にも～ない or ～にも～ず.

And yet another example is when lining things up (列挙)

> 日本にもアメリカにもメリットがあります (There are benefits for both America and Japan)

There are perhaps other examples of the usage also not mentioned above.